# How to use my fulltext lucerne index in Neo4j.rb?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, sinatra

OK, so originally I followed [this guide](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) to create a fulltext index, and then I imported all my data onto my Neo4j server. The indexes work great, and now I'm trying to use Sinatra/Ruby to interact with my Neo4j graph.

I'm using the Neo4j ruby gem, and I've created a model (movie.rb) of Movies with a fulltext index on the title [as per this wiki entry](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3AWrapper-Lucene#fulltext-and-exact):

```
class Movie
    include Neo4j::NodeMixin
    property :id
    property :movieID
    property :name, :index => :fulltext
    property :year
    property :imdB
    property :rtRating
    property :poster
end
```

However, I am getting this error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j::NodeMixin`. The Neo4j Ruby wiki entry states that:

> The neo4j-wrapper is included in the neo4j gem The neo4j-wrapper gem defines these mixins: Neo4j::NodeMixin

So it should be included in my project...

I have no idea how to continue... someone please help me search with my fulltext index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we've already helped you with this separately, but for anybody running across this question:

For various reasons, the Neo4j.rb project doesn't have good support for the legacy indexes.  That wiki page is out of date (I just updated it to say so).  The `searchkick` gem is recommended for fulltext search functionality with Neo4j.rb.

Also note that there is a direct integration of elasticsearch with Neo4j:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch

Here's a video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJLSFsXgOvA

For that, though, I believe you would need to make your own HTTP requests to Neo4j to get the results from the plugin.  The upside is that not all of your changes need to go through your Ruby app (like would be the case with `searchkick`)